# Google map fill color outside the circle

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, dictionary

I create a map based search for my project, I have need to dimmed the google map and contents inside the circle are clearly visible... like this website

http://housing.com/in/kolkata/buy/search?f=eyJuZWFyYnkiOnsibGF0IjoyMi41NDU4NSwibG5nIjo4OC4zNzUyNTU4OTk5OTk5NiwicmFkIjozODkwLCJuYW1lIjoiOS81QyIsInBvaW50X2lkIjoiZGE1NDU5MTBhYzg1MWUzZmRlZDY3YTA0YmZhMjEzZjQ4MTI1YWQ0YiJ9LCJvdmVycmlkZV9yYWRpdXMiOmZhbHNlfQ%3D%3D

Comment: Here is the html and javascript fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/naushrambo/LmhaK/

Comment: @naushrambo [don't just link to jsfiddle](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), _"also include the code in your question itself. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time"_